# How do I change which folder is being used for my git in vscode?

Tags: git

I had accidentally initialized my git repo into my base user folder. Quite obviously, I do not want to upload everything on my computer to a github repository. I've deleted the .git files in my base folder, however, vscode is still acting as if that is my desired git folder to track changes. I've reloaded my vscode, initialized a repository in the desired folder for my project, and nothing changes. Is there something I'm missing in order to change this folder within vscode's options? I didn't see anything that explicitly had a path to a desired github folder.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had removed my .git folder, I was incorrect. It has been removed, and the perceived issue has been fixed. Turns out, it was a pebkac error.